# Should we delete physical database for the deleted clients in SAAS application

Tags: sql-server, saas

I am working on a project which is in .net core and hosted on azure and being used as SAAS application by different clients all over the world having separate databases. 
Now I got a requirement which says we should delete the databases of those clients which are no longer in master db and deleted by admin.

I am in doubt that should we really delete the database for the clients which would be getting deleted?

Also if yes is it feasible to delete the database through application or we should use some utility to do that?

Also I am afraid if server will allow application to delete the database?

Can any one please suggest me on this?

Following tech stack i am using:
.net core (backend) with EF core
MSSQL (database)

Comment: Whether you "should" delete the DB is entirely your choice?

Do you have a technical question?

Comment: thanks for the response, how should we do that using .net core?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Theres a few different ways.. Essentially it works the same as any other database, so you can execute T-SQL to do it.. or use the Azure SDK.. Here is some examples of different approaches: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/drop-database-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

You can execute raw SQL statements in EF like so:

```
using(var context = new SampleContext()) 
{ 
    var commandText = "INSERT Categories (CategoryName) VALUES (@CategoryName)"; 
    var name = new SqlParameter("@CategoryName", "Test"); 
    context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(commandText, name); 
}
```

So, using that format, you could add your DROP Database command in? Taken from: https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/raw-sql - under the Database.ExecuteCommand section

Comment: Is there any way to do this using Entity Framework?